# How to change legend name in Grafana using regex?

Tags: regex, grafana

I am trying to change the names in a panel's legend in Grafana.

Basically my pane's legend names are in the form of:

```
somestring_someotherstring_somethirdstring.yetanotherstring
```

I'd like to just keep the name `somethirdstring`

My current attempt:

I go on the right-hand side of the panel where it says "Overrides" and attempt to replace the word `string` with nothing, but it does not work.

[image]

Can you please assist on how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Overrides don't support something like this. In such a way you will be able to rename all matched series to the same const string.

But you can use Transform "Rename by regex" with params like this:

```
Match: ([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^\.]+)\..+
Replace: $3
```